# Anonymous comment feature to explain anonymous downvote?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, comments, down-votes

Recently my questions were downvoted, though the reason for such is unknown to me (also it's not quite a big deal for me) but I believe that if the downvoter had given me some suggestions for improvement then I would be able to improve them. I believe that thee sole reason for this behavior found in the downvoter (i.e., the act of downvoting without commenting for improvement)  is the reason that that they feel that the OP might start downvoting their due to grudge. So I have a solution for it which is as follows:

> Whenever a person downvotes (either a question or an answer) a comment box should, which would be must to fill before down voting to be counted, appear which wouldn't require the downvoter to reveal their identity rather the comments be identified by a set of randomly generated  containing numbers as well as symbols and letters. In this manner the voter can downvote but in due process improve the post.

So what are the opinion of you people about this?

Comment: I sympathise, but allowing anonymous comments strikes me as asking for trouble ...

Comment: What would stop downvoters from leaving malicious unconstructive comments?

Comment: @John So what's the advantage of current feature!?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should downvoters have to comment on why they did it?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2817/)

Comment: None of the OP's question have an overall negative score so what gives?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero at the time I posted the question someone downvoted two of my questions but these questions are getting positive response (though no answer)

Answer (score 1):

To leave comments anonymously, choose a pseudonym for your display name. (As you have figured out, I think: I assume your display name is a reference to the famous Ramanujan, rather than your own name.)

Requirements that comments must accompany votes have been proposed and rejected numerous times network-wide.

Comment: The moderator agreement restricts what we can do with personally identifiable information (PII) like real names, and SE logs when we look at them. But plenty of people put obvious pseudonyms, or nothing at all, in the private PII fields as well. I haven't looked at your PII and I'm not planning to.

Comment: @Ramanujan In short, we don't have access to your real name unless you choose to share it with us by entering it into your profile (and even in that case, as rob said, we don't care)