# Instead of just down-voting a new post, can't the same person care to explain why?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, down-votes

I have a question about my Physics Stack Exchange post: [How to exactly evaluate the Magnetic Field associated with the given Electric Field in a lossy medium?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/533228/how-to-exactly-evaluate-the-magnetic-field-associated-with-the-given-electric-fi)

My question here is that instead of just down-voting my question that i just posted, shouldn't the same person explain why, especially if its the first few down-votes. I genuinely think that there should be such a rule.

Also, I fully admit that my question might not be of that standard which the viewer/ down-voter expects, but I'm also fully aware of the fact that i did not break any rules while asking my question. I first explained my question, then I also showed my effort in solving the question and then I finally explained what the real problem that I'm facing.

I mean surely there's not too wrong with this.

Hope that this sort of things get sorted quickly.

Also, hope for a decent answer or at least a half-decent reply.

Comment: There are several questions here about having such a rule.  https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12498/ https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2817/ https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1372/ and in those questions there are more links to the main meta where this is also discussed.  I wouldn't expect people to be required to explain downvotes, you can read reasons linked.

Comment: Also, see the rules for [check-my-work](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic) questions.  These are off-topic, and that is what your question appears to be.

Answer (score 5):

Requiring comments when somebody downvotes a question or answer [is something that has been brought up in the past](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2817/should-downvoters-have-to-comment-on-why-they-did-it) many times and each time it is declined. So I think the real motivation of my answer here is to help you decipher why your question was downvoted and why it is accumulating votes to close.

You stated you did not break any rules, but you sort of did -- if we consider what determines on or off topic as a "rule". Specifically, this question does not follow our policy on [asking homework-like or exercise-based questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange). It falls afoul of the [check-my-work type question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic) rule.

Your question presents the work and the problem, but it ends with:

> The problem for me here is that I'm not sure if this is the correct solution

and doesn't dive into the misconceptions that might lead to it, aside from being unfamiliar with the area in general. It might be salvageable if you can ask specific questions about the topic that help you understand the issues, rather than checking the math.

Lastly, the help text for a downvote says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." We take the view that check-my-work questions are not useful to anybody except the person asking it, and so that is likely the reason for the downvote. But again -- if you can re-write it to be about the physical concepts where you are confused, it can be a good question and then one downvote won't matter relative to the upvotes it gets.

---

As a final note, leaving comments that insult the people who might agree with the downvoter might make them less likely to help you. It's probably better to ask for help clarifying things, than to lash out at people.

Answer (score 4):

So I will come out at the person who downvoted your question on the main site and actually also downvoted your meta question.

I will point out (repeating what others have indicated in comments):

1. This is not a check-my-work site, so I downvoted the question on the main site.  I do not see how your rather specific question is beneficial beyond the specific answer.
2. A bit of searching on meta would have provided an answer to your query, so I downvoted your question on meta.

Answer (score -4):

Stackexchange is not a forum where people can discuss and learn by mutual messaging. It’s a kind of Question-Answer site, every community envisages a certain kind of goal and makes rules accordingly, so if Stackexchange have some rules regarding the homework questions or check my work posts then it is not something to be surprised of. We have some more rules, in forums you can verbally present your dislikeness for some post (and I must mind you sometimes it proves very dangerous) but here we got another choice of presenting our disapproval, i.e. downvote and although we can write ourselves regarding what we dislike about something but it’s sometimes best to leave a downvote.

Some people here have extreme intolerance towards the homework problems post, and it’s one of the reasons that you got **a** downvote. You’re very right in asking why the downvoter didn’t consider answering your question, I think if someone does that it will count as promoting something which the community restricts to do. But our community does allow normal discussions and solution to homework problems in [chats](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=physics.stackexchange.com), after you have gained some very minimal privileges you can certainly go and talk in there.

My friend why a single downvote has broken you? There are a lot and lots of opposition there in future, they will downvote your question/answer no matter how correct you will be, they will troll you, they will show no signs of understanding about your views, much more is yet to come. I’m not saying that this community is full of evil (no never) but it’s also not free from common evils. So, be strong and don’t let a red colour with “-2” demotivate you.

> Come on you raver, you seer of visions
>   Come on you painter, you piper, you prisoner, and shine.

Comment: *Some people here have extreme intolerance towards the homework problems post, and it’s one of the reasons that you got a downvote.* I will point out that it is the site policy that most homework-problems are off-topic. That is the reason for the down votes, not because people inherently hate homework problems.