# What should I do if my answer to a question has a downvote for no reason defined?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, down-votes

What should I do if my answer to a question has a downvote for no reason defined?

I do agree if there is maybe some mistake in my answer but I am not able to find. Then, yes. I agree with the downvote.

But for this answer, I don’t think a downvote was correct.

Also, I did write in the comments : “ Why the downvote?“.

What else should I do in this case?

https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/645911/287551   This is the answer.

Comment: The only thing you can do is improving your answer. Then let the community judge.

Comment: Related: *[Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135)*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not much that you can do other than improving your answer or hoping that the downvoter leaves a comment. Votes are private and there is no obligation for voters to explain themselves.

However, if someone targets you and votes on many of your posts in a short span of time, the system will automatically detect and revert the votes.

Comment: I have already improved the Q 2 - 3 times just so that someone notices if the downvote is not correct.

Comment: Do you from your own side think if there is Sth wrong ?

Comment: @SrijanM.T I am not the one who downvoted your answer, but in my opinion, while there is nothing wrong with your answer *per se*, it could have been organized/formatted in a clearer and more readable way.

Comment: I didn’t mean to say you down voted it. Ok. I’ll check on edit then

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @SrijanM.T You might already be notified, but I edited your answer to change some formatting. Feel free to further edit.

Comment: @Jonas Thank you.

Comment: @SrijanM.T People who have downvoted don't get notified when you make your edits. If they come back, they could change their vote, but there's no mechanism to pull them back to look. Some people will follow a Q&A where they voted, but some will not.

Comment: For prior discussions of a feature to notify downvoters of edits, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1751/263383 and its linked questions.

Answer (score -12):

I call downvoting without leaving a comment *cowardly downvoting*, since the downvoter didn't have courage to express/formulate their critique of the answer in the comments. It might be that they even do not understand the answer.

**Some reasons for *cowardly downvoting***
There may be multiple reasons for such downvoting:

- Some users treat *upvote/downvote* as *like/dislike* buttons on social networks, i.e., they do not realize that votes on SE are an equivalent of *peer review* in scientific community - they are not to express whether the answer pleases us, but to signal to other users whether it is correct or not. (Note also that many social networks nowadays do not offer a dislike button, to avoid bullying.)
- Sometimes downvotes come due to competing interests - the user may have also published an answer, and wants their answer to appear above yours, which may potentially bring more upvotes. Such competition may become especially sharp when dealing with bounty questions.
- It may be a user that you have recently argued with about something else, and who is now taking their revenge, without any relevance to the content of your question.
- Finally, in some cases downvoting is a form of a *collective punishlment* - the user may not like the question or the topic in general, and they downvote everyone's answer to discourage the discussion.

**Remark:** I do expect a few random downvotes by people who are offended by what I have written above - which would only confirm the points made.

**Suggestions for principled downvoting**
Here is the practice that I suggest for dealing with an answer that you do not like (which pretty much follows the tradition in scientific publications):

- Write a comment on the answer, explaining what you think is not correct. This way you a) give opportunity to other users to understand the issues and participate in the discussion, and b) give opportunity to the author to correct themselves or argue for their viewpoint.
- If you have discussed the issue with the author, and you still believe that the answer is incorrect/misleading, then downvote. Note however, that you will negate everything that is contained in the answer - so downvoting because of a minor issue, while the bulk of the answer is correct, is not necessarily a good idea.

**Update**
a few clarifications in view of the discussion in the comments:

- The main point of this answer was to stress the importance of leaving a comment when downvoting, not to discuss particular motivations.
- My least of reasons for downvoting that I consider illegitimate was not intended as comprehensive. I added qualifier "some" in the preceding sentence.
- There is disagreement about some of the reasons cited, at least to rhe extent that they are not excluded by SE policy. Still, others are clearly beyond the pale. Sadly, no one seems to have a problem with those (judging by the downvotes.)
- In any case, it is important to remember that everyone carries a moral responsibility for their own actions. When you downvote, it is *your* downvote. You own it, even if no one know.

**Update 2**
The reactions to this post seem to focus on only one type of situation - where obviously low quality content is downvoted by a high-reputation user. This was not however the situation that I had in mind when writing this post, as I hope should be clear from (re-)reading it. Given that most of the members in this community are either students or non-physicists, it could be very well that high-quality content is downvoted by the users who do not even understand it - due to the lack of background (general or specific to the question discussed) or due to not bothering to read the context freely. I wonder, if statistics is available on the number of downvotes by the reputation of the downvoters and the downvoted.

Comment: Your answer seems to suggest that the
 only reason to down vote is due to incorrect content, but that's not the only reason. There could be other issues that cause a post to deserve a down vote; as long as one thinks the post is not useful to the site for any reason then technically that is a valid reason to down vote. You also seem to suggest that if there is no comment with the down vote that it has to be due to one of the petty reasons you have listed. Of course it's always the best option to leave a comment, but lack of a comment doesn't necessarily mean an "invalid" down vote.

Comment: "*I do expect a few random downvotes by people who are offended by what I have written above - which would only confirm the points made.*" Of course, there isn't a way to actually confirm this is the case if this post were to receive down votes without comments. Maybe someone just disagrees with your answer, which is often what down votes on meta are used for, and so a comment wouldn't be needed. It doesn't mean someone is necessarily offended by what you have said (even though today many people do conflate disagreement with offense).

Comment: @BioPhysicist Note that I talk here specifically about downvoting answers. I do think the upvoting/downvoting are reserved for characterizing the scientific merits - for dealing with other issues SE offers plenty of options, such as flagging, closing, recommending deletion. As I described, downvoting without a comment may well be to a genuine disagreement with the answer... but without a comment we cannot judge this disagreement on its merits - it works both ways. Overall, I am trying to raise the ethical and scientific standards in this community.

Comment: That's fine to have your own standard of voting, but not all users will have that same standard, and the intent of down votes is to be broader than your standard. The most general, valid down vote reason is that one thinks the post (question or answer) is not useful for the site. Additionally, the down votes could be paired with the other actions you mentioned; they do not have to be mutually exclusive (they usually aren't).

Comment: @BioPhysicist Downvote should not be a *duplicate* for another action (just as one doesn't want duplicate questions) - it is totally unnecessary, and serves only to rub it in to the post author (see my remark about about no *dislike* button in social nets.) And whatever is the reason for downvote, the basic ethics/politeness is still to leave an explanatory comment.

Comment: I see where you're coming from in terms of your opinion, but that doesn't change what down votes are used for on this site. The [help center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down) says "*Downvotes should be used to indicate issues with quality, effort, or accuracy of a post*" and additionally says flags, etc. can be done in addition to down voting (or just as an alternative, which is what you prefer). I'm not trying to discuss preference with you here, just how the site actually works. I also agree that one should leave a comment, that was never in contention here.

Comment: @BioPhysicist A downvote without any explanation does not *indicate* anything. In principle, one could tighten the comunity standards - reducing redundancy would make the community more valuable. But my focus here is on ethical issues - that people can do whatever they like within the limits of law, doesn't make their behavior ethical, and doesn't mean that the others should remain silent about it.

Comment: Like I said above, I'm not trying to discuss commenting with down votes, which I already said I agree with you on; I'm not sure why it keeps going back to that as if I had said otherwise. I was just trying to talk about down vote reasons, which your answer here seems to have some misconceptions about. It's not unethical to down vote a post (question or answer) in addition to other methods like flagging if such action is warranted. You might disagree with that, but there is nothing morally wrong with it. If you think the down vote policy should be changed, I suppose that should be it's own post

Comment: @BioPhysicist The topic of the discussion was about downvoting without leaving a comment, which is why I insist on it. The other issue is dependent on it: if one feels reluctant to leave a comment "I downvoted, flagged and recomended closing your question.", one probably shouldn't do this anyhow. When one does something that the one is ashamed to cofess - this is clearly an ethical issue.

Comment: "Downvote should not be a duplicate for another action" - This is generally at odds with the overall philosophy of the SE system. I cannot quickly find the meta, but there are serious proposals to make systemwide changes such that, e.g., a vote to close or a flag would *automatically* also cast a downvote. That is to say to force what you're calling "duplication" rather than to eliminate it.

Comment: @Brick How would it serve the community? I accept the rules as they are, but I don't see the point of such duplication.

Comment: They are used differently on the backend, for example, so they aren't really duplicate. Maybe a mod could be more precise, but downvotes contribute to processes that do cleanup.  For example for answers: https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers.  For questions: https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions

Comment: @Blick that may make sense from the backend point of view - in fact, in some communities posts with many downvotes are automatically removed. However, from the point of view of science and the good of the community of physicists, I do not see much advantage in such redundancy.

Comment: As a particularly high rep user, I wonder if you might have forgotten how many of the other tools that you suggested earlier in the chain of comments are not available to everyone else?  You suggested instead using options "such as flagging, closing, recommending deletion", but, except for flagging, those come at higher rep levels than most people have.

Comment: @Brick It is particularly in regard to the lower community users that I would not encourage downvoting - "-2" hurts quite a bit when your reputation is a few hundred or lower (although I have seen high-rep users taking it hard way as well, when they saw no fault with their answer and no comment was left.) What could be automatized is demanding a reason for downvote and publishing the names of downvoters - as with the closure votes.

Comment: That would be become unbearably tedious, especially if it were extended to all sites including the really high volume sites. Whatever you may feel here, systemwide I feel reasonably confident that the number one reason for an anonymous downvote is that the person answering put so little effort into the answer that a comment isn't merited. It seems you want a different structure to the site where voting means something different than what it is on SE. That's fine, of course, but your characterization in the answer is, in my opinion, misleading and rude to users following the published guidance.

Comment: @Blick Please take no offense, but you are committing at least two logical fallacies here: a) *appeal to authority* (rather than debating the argument on its merits), and b) *straw man* (misrepresenting my intentions and attacking this misrepresentation). Also, despite my more general case against *duplicates*, my question specifically lists four the possible reasons for downvoting that I consider unprincipled - which of them do you think is a good practice?

Comment: I reject this one: "they do not realize that votes on SE are an equivalent of *peer review* in scientific community". This is not the point of votes on SE, ala the above. The one that you've pejoratively descried as "collective punishment" is also, at least debatably and in proper context, a legitimate process that's been discussed here in, e.g., the context of the "homework-like" questions and the (perceived) slow response time of the review process in closing them. You've also categorically called this "cowardly downvoting" - with cowardly being inflammatory and not particularly accurate.

Comment: @Brick So you support downvoting a question/answer regardless of its merits, just because you don't like it? *Cowardly* here clearly refers to downvoting without leaving a comment. *Collective punishment* refers to punishing others by association, for the fault that they didn't commit - you seem to support the concept, but disapprove the term. What exactly offends you - calling the things by their real name? Whatever is the disagreements about the reasons for downvoting, those who believe that their downvote is correct, are not ashamed to leave a comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126763/discussion-between-brick-and-roger-vadim).

Comment: I agree, the peer review point and the collective punishment point give me pause. 1)This is a Q&A site, not a peer-review process. Questions and answers that are not useful to the site get downvoted so that they are less visible to others. Of course people will not always down vote "correctly" or "justly", but ideally this is how votes work. 2) If users are answering questions that should have been closed, those answers are hurting the site, and thus I think it is a reasonable argument that those answers should be down voted.

Comment: @BioPhysicist 1) you are taking *peer review* point  out of context. Read the bullet in full, and you willfind harder to disagree - your argue yourself that downvotes should be motivated, even if we disagree about the valid motivations. 2) I repeat (for at least the third time in this thread) that the point is not what motivations we agree upon, but that motiva

Comment: ...but that a person downvoting without leaving a feedback, probably suspects that their motivation is doubtful. And this is probably what embarrass in my post - it calls for more personal responsibility and integrity, rather than hiding behind the rules.

Comment: Beware that accusing a specific user of “cowardice” would definitely violate the spirit of the [code of conduct](/help/conduct). (I don’t mean to suggest that’s what’s happening in this answer.) For me, when I downvote without commenting, it’s because that post is worth a half-minute or a minute to me to read it, but not five minutes or ten for me to write about it. A user who described my time-management decisions as “cowardice” would be acting in an unwelcoming way.

Comment: @rob You are speaking here about *your time* versus what is beneficial to *the community*. I think a downvote without a comment is offensive and disrespectful. Then, again, if you genuinely believe that my post is offensive - you need to delete it, not try to convince me to change my opinion ;)

Comment: Allowing users to cast votes (both down and up) anonymously is a *feature* that immensely benefits the community because it provides a mechanism by which people can express their opinion on a post without being judged for it. There are plenty of contexts in which the requirement to justify one's opinion with one's name attached to it considerably changes the willingness to actually express that opinion (e.g. think about why many elections have anonymous/secret ballots).

Comment: See https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2817/50583 for prior local and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/263383 and its linked questions for prior SE-global discussions about ideas of mandatory comments for downvotes.

Comment: @ACuriousMind What matters in science is not an *opinion*, but *evidence* and *logical arguments*, which should be available for everyone to judge. The correctness of physics theories is not decided by vote (I heard a claim that the US Congress once annuled the gravity.)

Comment: @RogerVadim But down votes apply to more than just correctness. The general purpose of down votes is to indicate quality for the PSE site (which encompasses correctness, but it is not only correctness)

Comment: @RogerVadim "*and publishing the names of downvoters*" I cannot agree with you on this because doing so will open a large can of worms and will very likely lead to targeted verbal abuse, harassments and so on, which only serves to make it more difficult for the moderators and, at the same time, being of zero constructive value. However, I *do* agree that downvoters should be notified when an answer is updated so that they can re-evaluate whether to maintain their downvote or not.

Comment: @RogerVadim I don't think anyone can doubt that rob has put a lot of time towards benefitting the community. If he decides that his time is better served doing other things to benefit the site rather than leaving comments that he doesn't think will be helpful, that's prudence, not cowardice.

Comment: @RogerVadim If you have some principles you stick to when it comes to downvoting, that's laudable. But you should understand that people have other principles that are equally valid.

Comment: @Chris I was answering rob's very clear comment that he downvotes but not comments.  I am not imposing my principles on anyone - rather it seems that there are quite a few people uncomfortable with me voicing a dissenting opinion.

Comment: @VincentThacker don't you think that downvoting can also be abusive? I think one should agree at least with some instances cited in my answer.

Comment: @RogerVadim Your post characterizes certain principles as "cowardly" and represents a list of reasons to downvote without leaving a comment as exhaustive. Certainly downvoting *can* be abusive (and we have tools to undo e.g. revenge downvoting) but that doesn't mean there aren't legitimate reasons to downvote without leaving a comment.

Comment: @Chris I didn't claim that my list was exhaustive. Again, as I noted above, if you find my post offensive, you need to delete it rather than argue with me - you are the moderator.

Comment: @Chris Just to finish with it:I listed practices, at least some of which are clearly abusive. The fact that three moderators go after me rather than simply suggesting one or two corrections and upholding my call for responsible downvoting, should give everyone a pause.

Comment: @RogerVadim Or maybe it means you just have views about how the site should work that are different than how it actually works; which is something moderators probably feel an obligation to point out. No one has "gone after you". You made a post that has some misconceptions about the site: there is going to be some discussion that arises from that.

Comment: @BioPhyicist the downvotes mean that people disagree with *everything* (or most) that I said. Also, I don't see the discussion here as particularly constructive or clarifying, except for your early comments. Finally, I am simply tired of arguing with several people, some of whom even didn't bother to read through and think over my post, before jumping into the fray.

Comment: @RogerVadim *" it seems that there are quite a few people uncomfortable with me voicing a dissenting opinion."* -- No, there are quite a few people dissenting with your opinion. --- Regarding the topic, I learned that there's certain types of answers where it is counterproductive to leave comments when downvoting -- all it will lead to is a lengthy discussion, with no progress made. That's the cases when I by now don't comment, as I feel (like rob) that my time is better spent otherwise. (And when I sometimes still comment in such cases, I later often regret it.)

Comment: I have removed a number of comments. This is a quick reminder that while speaking in generalities like the post does may be allowed here, personal attacks on specific users are not.

Comment: @RogerVadim If you are concerned another user is acting improperly, please raise the concern in a flag, not in a public comment. For what it's worth, there's no evidence of anything improper that I can see.

Comment: The ability to give anonymous feedback (in this case, the downvote is telling you something, even though it may not be specific) is an important facet of any rigorous review system.  I would welcome a system where comments can be left anonymously.

Comment: @ProfRob This is not a bad idea. Although, it is necessary to point out that anonymous feedback is common in physics, but by no means a universal practice elsewhere. And even in Phys. Rev., in case of disputes, the divisional editor signs their review.

Comment: Hi Roger, I think downvoting is really a more complicated thing than the points you bring up. Since most of us who open meta are frequenters of the site, then it turns out that revealing that one downvoted / upvoted may affect how the politics on the site works. It's quite hard to remove the 'human nature' part from how voting is taken. I suppose, this an inherent problem of democracy.

Comment: @Buraian I think assuming responsibility for one's own decisions is not incompatible with democracy. But I see what you mean.