Why my answer got downvoted?
So I recently wrote my answer to this question Can the Lorentz Transformation Matrix be Derived using the Change of Basis Formula? and I received one downvote without explanation. I wonder if there is anything wrong with my answer?

I’m not the person who downvoted but your answer just postulates the transformation without explanation.  Moreover, why make this 3d-spatial when you are doing (t,x)?  It’s not a good answer, although IMO it’s not worth a downvote either.

Related: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2817/

Related: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13633/174766

This question is similar to: Why is this question being downvoted?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.


Why my answer got downvoted?

Unfortunately, I can not answer this, since I am not the one who downvoted your answer.
The only person who could answer this for certain is the one who downvoted. But please understand it is considered poor form to demand to know who downvoted your answer (or question). Voting on questions and answers is anonymous and the mods generally are not going to disclose who voted and how (if they can even see that, maybe they can't).
If you are interested in general information about voting and reputation, see the help sections on that topic, for example this one.
If you are interested in general information about how to write a good answer, see the help sections on that topic, for example this one.

Also, if you would like, you can delete your answer and you will regain the lost rep from the downvote. But, as mentioned in the comments, please do not delete an answer and then repost the exact same answer (or you might get banned or otherwise punished).

Note that deleting an answer and reposting it unchanged, as a way to game the reputation system, is not okay. A better solution is just to not worry much about a single downvote, but instead to watch out for patterns.  I wouldn't let one anonymous downvote convince me to censor myself.
